# My horse was transported into the Nether

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I was playing Minecraft on my PS4 putting coal in the furnace, when I saw in the corner of my eye that my horse had disappeared! I went to the Nether portal and transported myself through it, and found my horse stuck in the Nether. I can't figure out a way to get it out of there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to either ride your horse out through your existing nether portal or build a bigger one. I can't find much on nether portals in the console edition but this website might help.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Portal

Comment: Could you use a lead?

Comment: If it's in the console version, then yes. Most my experience is in the PC and PE editions, and the console edition is kind of a combination of both.

Comment: I don't think the console version has a lead (or leash)